# Lucene BooleanQuery OR output not as wanted

Tags: java, lucene, booleanquery

i have an index with some documents, the 593 documents that contains the word **computer** and 51 documents that contains the word **science** and 596 documents that contains the words **computer OR science**, i wanna outpout those 596 docs here's my code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException{

        String[] champ ={"W", "A"};
       BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();

              BooleanQuery qIntermediaire;
        qIntermediaire = new BooleanQuery();
        for(int i=0;i<champ.length;i++){
           qIntermediaire.add(new BooleanClause(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(champ[i], "computer"), 0), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
       }
       q.add(new BooleanClause(qIntermediaire, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
       qIntermediaire = new BooleanQuery();
       for(int i=0;i<champ.length;i++){
           qIntermediaire.add(new BooleanClause(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(champ[i], "science"), 0), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
       }
       q.add(new BooleanClause(qIntermediaire, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));


         Path indexPath = Paths.get("MonIndex");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath);
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher iSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopDocs topdocs = iSearcher.search(q, 10000);
        ScoreDoc[] resultsList = topdocs.scoreDocs;

             System.out.println(resultsList.length);


    }

}
```

for some reasons this is giving me 461 documents :(

Comment: Should `new Term(champ[i], "pulls")` be `new Term(champ[i], "computer")`?

Comment: Yeah mb i forgot to edit on the post, was trying with other words when i copy pasted the code

Comment: It appears you have the wrong logic. Don't use fuzzy logic. Try the lucene version of `(champ[0] contains "computer" OR champ[1] contains "computer" OR ... champ[n] contains "computer") AND (champ[0] contains "science" OR champ[1] contains "science" OR ... champ[n] contains "science")`. I worked with lucene a while back and it was not uncommon to have queries fill a page.

Comment: I need to use fuzzy for the maxEdits :/

Comment: So use fuzzy, but my suggested logic still stands.

Comment: what's your W and A?